# C++ : Alternative to constructor initializer lists without assignment?

Tags: c++, memory, constructor, shared-ptr, list-initialization

I'm facing the following problem:

I want to pass the _partHandlePtr to the constructor of _currUnmanaged and _extUnmanaged but getting errors like "memory access violation occurred at address 0x00000010, while attempting to  read inaccessible data". I also tried to initialize both instances after 2) but the problem is that I can't use the assignment operator on them. So is there another option to initialize _currUnmanaged and _extUnmanaged without using list initialization or is the problem elsewhere?

```
class DerivedCollect {

    DerivedCollect(
        const IGCollect& inputCollect,
        Handle handle) :
        _partHandlePtr(nullptr),
        _currUnmanaged(_partHandlePtr),
        _extUnmanaged(_partHandlePtr)
    {
        // 1) Filling _pHandles 

        _pHandles.push_back(HandleManager::GetPHandle(handle));

        for (const auto& it : inputCollect.GetPartHandles())
        {
            _pHandles.emplace_back(it);
        }

        // 2) Make _partHandlePtr referencing to _pHandles 

        _partHandlePtr = std::make_shared<std::vector<Handle>>(_pHandles);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Handle>> _partHandlePtr;
    std::vector<Handle> _pHandles;
    UnmanagedCollect _currUnmanaged;
    UnmanagedCollect _extUnmanaged;
}
```

```
class UnmanagedCollect {
    UnmanagedCollect(
        std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Handle>> partHandlePtr) :
        _partHandlePtr(partHandlePtr)
    {
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Handle>> _partHandlePtr;
}
```

Thanks for suggestions and solutions!

Comment: You'd have to move the assignment of `_currUnmanaged` and `_extUnmanaged` within your constructor body *after* you assign `_partHandlePtr` because otherwise they're not pointing at the `shared_ptr` you allocated later

Comment: @CoryKramer and how can I do this if the assignment operator is deleted?

Comment: I don't know what `UnmanagedCollect` is so I don't know how to answer that, but in some way you need to defer the initialization of those objects

Comment: You\re creating a shared-ownership *copy* of the initial `pHandles`. I believe you have misunderstood `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @molbdnilo possibly xD Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: @CoryKramer added the class and its constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that what you're aiming for is to have one vector of "handles" that is shared (initially) with the two "unmanaged"  members.

That would look something like this:

```
class DerivedCollect 
{
    DerivedCollect(
        const IGCollect& inputCollect,
        Handle handle) :
        _partHandles(std::make_shared<std::vector<Handle>()),
        _currUnmanaged(_partHandles),
        _extUnmanaged(_partHandles)
    {
        _partHandles->emplace_back(HandleManager::GetPHandle(handle));

        for (const auto& it : inputCollect.GetPartHandles())
        {
            _partHandles->emplace_back(it);
        }
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Handle>> _partHandles;
    UnmanagedCollect _currUnmanaged;
    UnmanagedCollect _extUnmanaged;
};
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! My code was really weird, I see that now :)

Comment: Ok it seems that there is still an error. It says that _partHandles is still uninitialized...do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Who is the "it" that says that and when does it say it?

Comment: The build process when _partHandles is passed to _currUnmanaged and _extUnmanaged

Comment: That's impossible unless your actual code declares the member variables in a different order.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score -1):

The assignment of _currUnmanaged and _extUnmanaged should be moved within the constructor